# create PDF from cshtml without any DLLs present in wwwroot folder

Tags: javascript, linux, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I want to create PDF from a cshtml file i.e., view. I used Rotativa, DinkToPdf, Select.HtmlToPdf but they all require wkhtmlpdf and some other DLLs present in solution. On server the path to the DLLs are not being found, on Linux server to be precise. It says
*"An error occurred trying to start process '/app//wwwroot/Rotativa/wkhtmltopdf' with working directory '/app//wwwroot/Rotativa'. No such file or directory"*

please provide new technique to convert cshtml to pdf or fix this issue.

I expect a functionality of creating PDF from cshtml templates without any external DLLs

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Linux does not have or use DLLs. If you get an error that something is missing, you probably should look around if it's somewhere else, or what's going on -- or if you have even installed it at all. We don't know what you have done so far if you don't include that.

Answer (score 0):

you can conside using the IronPdf library.
Here's an example

```
Install-Package IronPdf
using IronPdf;

// Your CSHTML content
string cshtmlContent = "<html><body><h1>Hello, PDF!</h1></body></html>";

// Initialize IronPdf Renderer
var renderer = new HtmlToPdf();

// Convert HTML to PDF
var pdfDocument = renderer.RenderHtmlAsPdf(cshtmlContent);

// Save PDF to a file or stream
pdfDocument.SaveAs("output.pdf");
```